# Flask Shell Commands not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, flask

I'm new to python and flask and currently working on the [Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database), however: I'm stuck getting `flask shell` to recognize my custom symbols/commands.

When I try to access the model `User` as a symbol by typing `flask shell` in my virtual environment, I get `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`.

`User` should return: `<class 'application.models.User'>`, but shows the error instead.

What I don't understand is that the `app` symbol seems to work fine and returns `<Flask 'application'>` as it should.

*What am I doing wrong here? Something with the imports?*

I did some research: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005343/accessing-user-model-from-flask-shell-raises-nameerror) looks like my problem but does not use the `app.sell_context_processor` decorator.

I tried also variations of my code: both changing import names from app to application as I changed these from the default in the tutorial and using `user` instead of `User` (lower vs. uppercase), but nothing seems to work.

Please help me fix this!

**Error**

```
    (venv) MBP:books mbpp$ flask shell
    Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
    App: application
    Instance: /Users/mbpp/Sites/books/instance
    >>> app
    <Flask 'application'>
    >>> User
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

**My code** from *application.py*

```
   from application import app, db
   from application.models import User, Book, State, Course, BookTitle, Author

   @app.shell_context_processor
   def make_shell_context():
       return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'State': State, 'BookTitle': BookTitle, 'Author': Author}
```

and from ***__init__.py***

```
    from flask import Flask
    from config import Config
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
    from flask_login import LoginManager

    # initiate the Flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # use the config.py file for configuration
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # use SQLAlchemy for database management
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # use Flask-Migrate extension for database migration management
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    # use Flask-Login extension for login form
    login = LoginManager(app)
    login.login_view = 'login'

    from application import routes, models
```

and from ***models.py*** (I'm building a website where users can sell books)

```
   from application import db, login
   from datetime import datetime
   from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, 
   check_password_hash
   from flask_login import UserMixin

   # create a table to store users
   class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
        password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
        phone = db.Column(db.String(64))
        books = db.relationship('Book', backref='seller_name', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: {}>'.format(self.username)

    # create a password hash
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    # check the password hash against a user given password
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    # create a table to store information on a book for sale
        class Book(db.Model):
            id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
            course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id'))
            title = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('booktitle.id'))
            author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))
            price = db.Column(db.Integer)
            isbn = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
            state_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('state.id'))
            state_description = db.Column(db.String(256))
            seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
            creation_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index = True, default = datetime.utcnow)

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Book: {}>'.format(self.title)

    # create a table to store different states books can be in
        class State(db.Model):
            id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
            name = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True)
            books = db.relationship('Book', backref='state', lazy='dynamic')

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<State: {}>'.format(self.name)

    # create a table to store courses
        class Course(db.Model):
            id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
            name = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True)
            year = db.Column(db.Integer, index = True)
            books = db.relationship('Book', backref='course', lazy='dynamic')

        def __repr__(self):
        return '<Course: {}>'.format(self.name)

    # create a table to store booktitles
        class BookTitle(db.Model):
            id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
            title = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True)
            books = db.relationship('Book', backref='book_title', lazy='dynamic')

        def __repr__(self):
           return '<Book title: {}>'.format(self.title)

    # create a table to store authors
        class Author(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True)
        books = db.relationship('Book', backref='author_name', lazy='dynamic')

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Author: {}>'.format(self.name)

     # user loader for Flask-Login extension, gets users ID
     @login.user_loader
     def load_user(id):
         return User.query.get(int(id))
```

Comment: You consistently misspelled `user` with a lowercase `U`.

Comment: @tripleee Just tried to use `User` in the `flask shell`, but that gives the same error. :/ Or is that not what you mean by *consistently*?

Comment: That's what I mean. Maybe [edit] the question to clarify this. I'm unfamiliar with this part of Flask but expecting a misspelled name to work is obviously unrealistic.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, edited the Q to clarify that I tried both `User` and `user`.

Comment: @StackTT what is the value of your `FLASK_APP` environment variable?

Comment: @Miguel `export FLASK_APP=application.py`

Comment: so you have a `application.py` and a `application` package in the same directory level? Can you disambiguate that to make sure that isn't the source of the problem?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, I have an application.py and a /application/ folder with /templates/ (for html tamplets) and __init__.py, routes.py, models.py and others in it. Should I change that folder name or application.py file name?

Comment: Doesn't matter which, pick one and change it. You can't have a module and a package of the same name, there is no way to be specific about which one of the two you are importing from.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks a lot Miguel, that works indeed. Changed my application.py into theapp.py and now `flask shell` works like a charm! I also did not need to change anything in my files, apart from running `export FLASK_APP=theapp.py`.

Comment: @Miguel If you want to submit your answer I'm ready to accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks a lot to [Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904393/miguel), the writer of the FLASK Mega Tutorial ([go check that out](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)) wo solved my problem!

As he pointed out in [a comment below my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626250/flask-shell-commands-can-not-access-user-model?noredirect=1#comment86367163_49626250): you cannot have a module and a package with the same name. So no application folder and application.py at the same time.

### **Solution:**

I changed my 'application.py into 'theapp.py' and now `flask shell` works like a charm! I did not need to change anything in my files, apart from running `export FLASK_APP=theapp.py` in the terminal.

Comment: This one have worked for me as well. It should be included as a warning on the tutorial, though.

Comment: Does not work for me. I had also used `microblog` for both the script and the dir. Changed the script to app.py and fixed the references. flask shell does not register it and the environment is set. I checked with `from envs import env` then `env("FLASK_APP")` which prints `'app.py'`. It did also not work by setting `export FLASK_APP=app.py` as an alternative method.

Comment: Found the issue. By comparing with the premade code, I found that my `app.py` file should be in the main dir, not inside the `app` dir.

Comment: Further info on the background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393861/how-python-deals-with-module-and-package-having-the-same-name

Comment: depending on your application set up, you can use a "manage.py" script for managing some setup including the shell context you need a @app.shell_context_processor decorator and make_shell_context() function which returns a "context" dictionnary mapping from "Model" Object to "Context" Object (making them visible in the shell context)

Answer (score 12):

Flask needs to be told how to import it, by setting the

```
FLASK_APP:(venv) $ export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
```

If you are using Microsoft Windows, use `set` instead of `export` in the command above.