# Problem with enviromental variable on different flask projects

Tags: python, linux, flask, environment-variables

I have the problem that I get a Name Error like `NameError: name 'db' is not defined` while using `flask shell` and accessing Modules and Classes

basically the same problem as in this question  [Flask Shell Commands not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626250/flask-shell-commands-not-working)


I have tried all the recommended solution but there did not solve the problem.
After some testing, I found out that the flask shell command worked correctly on my first flask project I got no NameErrors there.

Only on my other flask projects which contains basically the same code, I get the Name Error. What could be the cause of that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused by the IDLE, when I have created a virtual env via Pycharm the problem occured, setting the virtualenv via commands solved the problem.